# Conditional Formatting on Google Sheets (based on multiple inputs)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to highlight a cell (CC3) yellow based on if the numbers in BK3 and BN3 are greater than or equal to 80.

I can figure out how to make it work based on one argument, but not the second. I'm also not married to turning it yellow, entering a word would be fine too. (Color just jumps out more.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a custom formatting based on a Custom Formula  So set the *Format cells if...* to Custom formula is and make the formula:

```
=AND($BK2>80, $BN2>80)
```

This is for a range defined as CC2:CC and it wil be applied to every cell in that range when columns BK and BN are greater than 80.  The $ will hold the column.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton. I knew it couldn't be too complex, but the comma inside the parenthesis was something I hadn't tried!

Comment: The [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) is always a good reference.